# android vertical gallery..?

Tags: android, gallery, carousel

can anybody please tell me how to create vertical gallery in android?
Is it possible to create vertical gallery in android..?

```
class mygallery extends Gallery{



}
```

thanx
Nilesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I believe it is not possible to do a vertical gallery with the default gallery widget in android. Even I had this requirement but I couldn't achieve it. So what I did is I created a listview with images and made it look like a gallery.

Comment: You have to use custom adapter. Look at this. Try modifying it accordingly http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html

Comment: Thnx to every 1 - got the ans to create vertical gallery .just create a circular list view.